# Code 401 when issuing a POST request through Android

Tags: android, ajax, rest, http-post, unauthorized

When I'm accessing a URL with Postman it works fine, but through Android I'm getting a 401 error:

```
04-07 03:53:26.920 850-1142/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {cmp=vems.visioneering.com.vems/.utils.ProfileActivity} from uid 10061 on display 0
04-07 03:53:26.957 26244-26244/vems.visioneering.com.vems V/Action ID: http://192.168.16.2:8081/VEMS/rest/ajax/getProfileObj
04-07 03:53:26.962 26244-26273/vems.visioneering.com.vems W/DefaultRequestDirector: Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
04-07 03:53:26.962 26244-26273/vems.visioneering.com.vems V/httpResponse: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@83d69b6
04-07 03:53:26.962 26244-26273/vems.visioneering.com.vems V/Status code: 401
04-07 03:53:26.963 26244-26244/vems.visioneering.com.vems D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

My Code is:

```
try {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[1]);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(params[0]);
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
    Log.v("httpResponse ",httpResponse.toString());

    int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    Log.v("Status code", String.valueOf(statusCode));
    if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ||
        statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response=EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        Log.v("RESPONSE SERVER COMM : ",response);
        return response;
    }
} catch (Exception e){
// ...
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Did you lookup what 401 means?

Comment: yes I look up ..It make succesfully login but not hitting this URL

Comment: could you share the request you are using in postman? You are not setting any user/credential parameters in your code, and since you are getting a 401, you are probably missing this. (http.401 == unauthorized)

Answer (score 0):

User Session management additionally requires the following header:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Your code", "Your code");
```

Answer (score 0):

status code 401 means unauthorized. It should have something to do with,
1. The certificates 
2. Login credentials
3. Access token